# UICollectionView items order changes everytime I scrolled. Only happens with new SDK 6.1? Is it a bug?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am doing something very simple --- created a uicollectionview horizontally, add a button, label it with the indexpath.row (or indexpath.item, doesn't seem to matter) , which should show as

"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...."

but as soon as I scrolled back and forth, the numbers are completely out of wack, like

"5,11,4,6,2,3,7"

and the order keeps changing if I scroll.

I am thinking it has something to do with cell reuse, but I don't know how NOT to reuse cell. I never have this problem before I upgrade my Xcode to get the SDK 6.1....is this a bug or am I really doing this wrong??? How to solve it? Please help!

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"textbutton" forIndexPath:indexPath];

....}
```

Comment: post complete datasource code

Comment: Oh, I don't think that's neccessary...the issue is in the reusing (which is the line I posted)

Comment: it is necessary, we want to know how you are setting label. A single line of code do not make much sense in all case

Comment: Are there any solutions for this behavior?

Comment: @minjiera i have the same problem, have you solve?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-set the content cell after it was reused. You can't rely on the content of a reused cell. You are only allowed to reuse the layout of a view. Not its content.

Comment: ? What does it mean? I dont understand

Comment: means the cell's visual properties such as height and width will be preserved. But the content will be refreshed